# Define java pojo for XML with single parent

Tags: java, xml, pojo, jackson-dataformat-xml

I'm not sure how to generate a java pojo for the below XML which has only parent (Data)

My XML

```
<Data>
<userID>100</userID>
<userName>user 100</userName>
<userID>101</userID>
<userName>user 101</userName>
<userID>102</userID>
<userName>user 102</userName>
</Data>
```

Any leads?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do it with 2 classes like this:

```
class Data {
        @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
        private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
}

class User {
    private String userID;
    private String userName;
}
```

Comment: This will produces the below :<Data>
<users>
<userID></userID>
<userName></userName>
</users>
<users>
<userID></userID>
<userName></userName>
</users>
<users>
<userID></userID>
<userName></userName>
</users>
</Data> but my requirement is to produce without <users>